# Sum() MySQL - PHP

Tags: mysql

I want to show Sum Total to (ID = 37) for this month

my code :

```
SELECT SUM(Total) 
FROM invoices 
WHERE user_id = 37 
And ModifiedTime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL (DAY(CURDATE())-1) DAY) 
AND LAST_DAY(NOW())
```

the result = NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT SUM(Total) 
FROM invoices 
WHERE user_id=37 
  And MONTH(ModifiedTime) = MONTH(now())
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query:-

```
SELECT SUM(Total) 
FROM invoices 
WHERE user_id = 37 
And ModifiedTime BETWEEN "'.date('Y-m-01 00:00:00').'" AND "'.date('Y-m-t').' 23:59:59"
```

This will gives u only current month records sum.
date('Y-m-01 00:00:00') gives u first day of current month.
date('Y-m-t') gives u current day.

Answer (score 0):

You should write:

```
SELECT SUM(Total) 
FROM invoices 
WHERE user_id='37' 
  And ModifiedTime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL (DAY(CURDATE())-1) DAY) AND LAST_DAY(NOW())
```

See that user-Id have been wrapped by single quotes.

If you still don't get a result you should show your data and table structure (maybe a fiddle?)